# Improving performance of MySQL query with a nested subquery with an IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I want to improve the performance of the following query.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT StringId 
FROM    translations 
WHERE   status = 1  
AND     TranslationId IN 
( 
    SELECT  Max(TranslationId) 
    FROM    translations  
    WHERE   languageId = 2 
    AND     TranslationId > 0  
    GROUP BY StringId;
```

This query currently takes forever because In clause.

The following subquery

```
SELECT  Max(TranslationId) 
FROM    translations  
WHERE   languageId = 2 
AND     TranslationId > 0  
GROUP BY StringId;
```

returns 16,000 rows and IN clause with 16,000 rows is what is taking so long.

An improved query that I came up with is

```
SELECT  DISTINCT t1.StringId 
FROM    translations t1 
INNER JOIN 
(   
    SELECT  Max(TranslationId) MaxTranslationId, 
            StringId 
    FROM    translations  
    WHERE   languageId = 2 
    AND     TranslationId > 0  
    GROUP BY StringId
) t2    ON  t1.StringId = t2.StringId 
        AND t1.TranslationId = t2.MaxTranslationId 
WHERE   status = 1;
```

I hope the inner join would return only rows that match both StringId and Max(TranslationId) like just using In clause.

Can somebody give me an answer if this is a right way to approach?

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQL Server?  Pick one.  They're not the same.

Comment: @Siyual I said MySQL in the title :)

Comment: This looks to be the correct approach.  The `Inner Join` should give you the results you're looking for, and a bit quicker.

Comment: Your query is missing an alias on `StringId`, so it will generate an error.  The approach seems ok, but there might be a more efficient version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is an alternative approach that uses `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.StringId 
FROM translations t
WHERE status = 1 AND
      NOT EXISTS (select 1
                  from translations t2
                  where t2.languageId = 2 and
                        t2.StringId = t.StringId and
                        t2.translationId > t.translationId
                 ) AND
      EXISTS (select 1
              from translations t2
              where t2.languageId = 2 and
                    t2.StringId = t.StringId and
                    t2.translationId > 0
                 )
```

For performance, you want an index on `translations(StringId, languageId, translationId)`.  This eliminates one of the aggregations, replacing it with an index lookup, which very well might be faster.

EDIT:  The above should work.  But, this might also be relatively efficient:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT StringId 
FROM    translations t
WHERE   status = 1 AND
        t.TranslationId = (SELECT  Max(t2.TranslationId) 
                           FROM    translations t2
                           WHERE   t2.languageId = 2 AND t2.TranslationId > 0 AND
                                   t2.StringId = t.StringId
                          );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you elaborate a little more on how eliminates Max aggregation? I have run both queries and they are giving me different results :(

Comment: @CoderSpinoza . . . Is `TranslationId` unique in the table?  Or is the pair `TranslationId, StringId` unique?

Comment: @CoderSpinoza . . . Very interesting.  I think I spotted the problem.  The condition `t2.translationId > 0` has an interesting effect.  You want to filter out rows where `t2.translationId = 0`, but the original query wasn't doing that.